# How do I add a repository, but only for a specific package/version and its dependencies?

Tags: package-management, apt, repository, pinning

I would like to use the Natty Narwhal repository for puppet packages, but I don’t want to upgrade my whole server. Is that possible ?

My current solution is to fetch the .deb packages by hand

Comment: What you want is something called 'pinning' , I'm sending this over to Ubuntu SE where you stand a better chance of getting help.

Answer (score 6):

[Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) is an advanced package management technique that allows you to remain on a stable release while grabbing packages from a more recent version. Mixing repositories is not supported, and can get you into trouble if the package you want has been compiled against different library versions than you have on your system. If possible, you should try getting the package from the [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) repository (or possibly a well supported PPA) first. That said, you seem to already know that `puppet` from Natty works well on your system.

In order to pin `puppet` to the natty version, we will have to edit a few files. First you will need to set your default release in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu` (I'm assuming you are using lucid, obviously substitute the actual release):

```
APT
{
Default-Release "lucid";
};
```

Next, you need to add natty to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or create a the new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/natty.sources.list` with the following sources:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then, you need to set the "Pin-Priority" for the `puppet` package from Natty higher than the priority for your default release. Setting the default release in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu` essentially sets the priority for all packages originating in that release to 990. So in `/etc/apt/preferences` we need to over-ride this for `puppet`, using something higher like:

```
Package: puppet
Pin: release n=natty
Pin-Priority: 995
```

Now you simply need to run and `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Comment: This worked well for me, but still left the future-versioned repos I had to add with a "500" priority, which I still find to be too high.  I tried to pin everything EXCEPT the stuff I needed lower using `Package: *
Pin: release n=yakkety
Pin-Priority: 400`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Also I think it's worth doing a dry-install of the packages you want from the newer repo to see if any other dependent packages need updating.  Then you can note them and space-separate them in the "Package:" line of the preferences file.