# How to install 11.10 package on 11.04?

Tags: apt, official-repositories

I use rsnapshot to backup various machines, and there is a bug fix between 1.3.1-1 and 1.3.1-3 which is important to me. Unfortunately, this bug fix is only packaged for Oneiric, and a couple of my machines are still running Natty.

Is there a simple way of installing this package from the Oneiric repository on my Natty machines?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the .deb and install it through dpkg -i package name?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I *could* do that. I could also download it from source, etc. But I'd much rather simply grab it from the repo. Not least of all because it's tested, etc., and I use Puppet to manage these boxes.

Comment: @Jorge Castro, why are you even bothering to edit the title? Is it really that important to you? I wrote it a particular way on purpose. For me, the Ubuntu version numbers take effort to think about (being all 0s, 1s and 4s for the last 2 years), whereas the codenames are far more useful.

Comment: We don't do codenames on this site as officially the releases are numbered. But if you feel that strongly about it feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you can accomplish this with apt-pinning.

A basic howto for beginners can be found here; http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Once I new that "pinning" was the thing I was looking for, I got it working with the help of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto and http://askubuntu.com/questions/27685/how-do-i-add-a-repository-but-only-for-a-specific-package-version-and-its-depen